# Send complex Obj (with Map) by POST body - JSON

Tags: java, rest, post, jax-rs, postman

I have got object with below structure:

```
class MyObject{
    private String firstString;
    private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
    private NestedObject nestedObject;
    private Map<String, String> map;
}
```

And I would like to create a `POST` call via *Postman* with below `JSON`:

```
{
  "firstString": "first",
  "bigDecimal": 1.2222,
  "nestedObject": {
    "secondString": "second"
  },
  "param1": "paramValue1",
  "param2": "paramValue2",
  "param3": "paramValue3"
}
```

I tried also:

```
{
  "firstString": "first",
  "bigDecimal": 1.2222,
  "nestedObject": {
    "secondString": "second"
  },
  "customMap" :{ 
     "param1": "paramValue1",
     "param2": "paramValue2",
     "param3": "paramValue3"
  }
}
```

I would like to treat `param1`, `param2`, `param3` as a `Map` *key - value*, because the parameters will be unknown (amount of elements could be 1 or 1000) and I would like to parse it as one of the step after receive this body.

`NestedObject` is an exactly nested object with known structure.

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getEntity( MyObject myObject){

  //sth
}
```

When I do this exactly as above after call I get Object but map variable is a null. How can I solve this problem, do you have any ideas ?

EDIT additional info:
@lealceldeiro Below you can find my code, is there any "suspicious" part?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class SearchParamsFromRequest {

    private NestedObject nestedObject;

    private String surname;
    private String type;
    private String userName;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

```
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String getString (SearchParamsFromRequest searchParameters){

        return "Any String";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations) in order to do that.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class MyObject {

    private String firstString;
    private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
    private NestedObject nestedObject;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    // you can change it to Map<String, String> if you know they will always
    // be string - string, be consistent with `setAdditionalProperty`

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
        return this.map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.map.put(name, value);
    }
    // getters and setters omitted
    // REMEMBER to follow the java beans naming conventions
    // for example call the setters and getters such as `setFirstName` and `getFirstName` for the `firstName` attribute
}
```

This (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) can help you to get your classes generated from sources such as JSONs.

Comment: Unfortunately after applying your proposal solution `map` is still empty, there are not set any `param`. I checked 3 times whether JSON schema and class model is OK, but everything looks correct.

Comment: Hmm... weird... Please, can you check whether `private Map<String, Object> map`, `Map<String, Object> getMap() ` and `setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value)` operate on the same values? `String`, `Object` both of them or `String`, `String` both of them too. The [JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) annotation is very clear about that: _Marker annotation that can be used to define a method to be used as a "fallback" handler for all otherwise unrecognized properties found from JSON content_

Comment: Moreover, I have used this in more than one project and it has always worked like charm. There must be something else interfering here. If you thing there is something else that could cause the problem, please, share it if you can.